# Xamarin.Forms - Select keyboard language

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-softkeyboard

In Xamarin.Forms, is there any way to choose the keyboard language programmatically. For example, I have a search test field where user have to type in non-English language, suppose Malayalam.
When the user tap the search box, the keyboard should come with Malayalam layout ( of course, if the language is installed)

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a standard way to do this. [This earlier question is still open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38302236/199364). [This feature request is still open](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9377). Possible work-arounds: 1) Create your own custom keyboard (that you somehow force to the correct layout - I'm not sure how). 2) Alter the app's culture, then open a new page. This requires platform specific code for each platform. These are topics you could google for info about. Sorry to not have a more concrete solution.